# Multiple IPs bound to one NIC on Windows

Tags: .net, winapi, network-programming

I'm looking for a way to bind multiple IP addresses to one NIC in Windows.

I need to write a simple webserver which listens on one IP address (a default service IP address) and lets me alter the second address via browser interface.

On Linux, I could bind multiple IP addresses to one card like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1 netmask ....
iface eth0:1 inet static
....
iface eth0:2 inet dhcp
....
```

However, I need this functionality on Windows. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NIC can have multiple IP addresses assigned to it, but those are part of the NIC's configuration, not something you generally manage in code or script.  Either way, when you create a listening socket in Windows, you have to bind it to the desired IP, not to the NIC directly.  A given IP can only be used by one NIC at a time.  If you want to have a server listening on all of the IPs of a given NIC, you have to create and bind a separate socket for each IP on that NIC.

Comment: I need to be able to change the NIC's configuration over a webinterface, so that the service technician is then able to change the other one of those two ips via browser. Is there any WinAPI call that lets me alter the configuration?

Comment: I think I found one here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366306(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As that page documents, such functions only support IPv4, and the IPs are not persistent across reboots.